# How does one decode bytes from QR code in Java?

Tags: java, node.js, buffer, qr-code, bytebuffer

Imagine I've got this example Node buffer `Buffer.from([1,2,3])` which I've encoded into a QR code as specified by the `qrcode` npm package's documentation.

```
const buffer = Buffer.from([1, 2, 3]);

QRCode.toFile(`public/images/${product.name}.png`, [{ data: buffer, mode: 'byte' }], {
  color: { light: '#0000' },
}, (err) => { if (err) throw err; });)
```

This is the output:

[image]

Now I must recover those encoded bytes over at my Android application. I'm currently using Zxing and the output looks like this. Unfortunately, there's a bunch of formatting bytes added into the mix in the beginning and end (ec 11 ec 11...).

[image]

A more complex example yields the same results. For buffer `16 76 20 42 3f 5d 4d d5 82 9a 45 19 32 90 19 53 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 63 0e 46 72 6f 7a 65 6e 20 4c 61 73 61 67 6e 65`, here's the Zxing  decoding:

[image]

What is that `427` value at the start and how do I get rid of it? Because otherwise the data looks good. How would I go about retrieving my ByteBuffer back?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? In your first example, you have encoded values 1, 2 and 3 as text. The parsed result correctly shows 3 characters, and since 1, 2 and 3 are not printable character values, it shows you question marks. Of course the raw bytes are longer because there is a data structure around your values that tells the reader what type of QR code they are looking at. In your second example, you haven't shown what you have encoded to come up with that parsed result. It looks like the first bunch of characters are not valid character values.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Disregard the raw text, I just need to extract the bytes I've pushed onto my Node buffer but the QR formatting pushed extra bytes to the top and bottom of the raw byte array. I was wondering whether there's a way to extract the original bytes. If you look closely on the second example, the buffer is correctly represented aside from the first three numbers (427).

Comment: `427` means: `4` - you're using `byte` encoding. `27` means that you have 39 (27 is hexadecimal for 39) characters in the block. It's part of the QR encoding. You can't get rid of it. Look at this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

Comment: Your problem is the zxing doesn't support returning binary data - it always tries to convert to a Java String, and doesn't give you access to the binary data. Your approach using base64 works, but makes your QR codes more complex as it stored more data. See the duplicate for other solutions.

Comment: I'm looking where to change in zxing so it returns back the binary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending too much time I'm ashamed of revealing, I've found a way to fix it.

The solution was encoding the buffer into Base64.

```
const buffer = Buffer.from([1, 2, 3]);

QRCode.toFile(`public/images/${product.name}.png`, buffer.toString('base64'), {
  color: { light: '#0000' },
}, (err) => { if (err) throw err; });)
```

Then over at Java, just decode it.

```
byte[] res = Base64.getDecoder().decode(rawResult.getText());
```

The resulting bytes no longer include the formatting as they otherwise would via the previous approach.

Comment: Of course. But I'm in 8 bit micro-controller and I have to encode the hex bytes array as it is without other huss fuzz. Still on it....